# In IntelliJ IDEA, what is the proper way to create and execute kotlin scripts (.kts) that depends on code in my project?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, scripting

I have a simple IntelliJ IDEA kotlin project with standard directory layout, i.e.:

```
src/
  main/
    kotlin/
      ClassA.kts
      ClassB.kts
    resources/
  test/
    kotlin/
      TestClassA.kts
      TestClassB.kts
```

In this project I want to use kotlin scripts (.kts files) and I want to use IntelliJ to edit and execute these scripts.

Inside the scripts I need to use classes, functions etc. defined in `main`, like `ClassA` (using stuff from `test` would also be nice). To aid in writing the scripts, I would like to get code completion and other coding assistance from IntelliJ.

Questions:

- Where should I put the `.kts` files?
- How do I specify that the script(s) should use my project's classpath when executing scripts?
- How do I make IntelliJ provide code completion in the script file?
- To me it looks like only kotlin scratch files and kotlin worksheet files work properly (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/run-code-snippets.html).
- What I want is proper scripts that are stored along the other source code in the project, and a way to run them either from IntelliJ run configurations or from the terminal.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 / kotlin plugin 223-1.7.21-release-272-IJ8214.52.

See also the IntelliJ issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55833/Kotlin-scripting-should-have-more-documentation-and-it-should-be-easier-to-execute-scripts-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `.main.kts` is that it's simple and doesn't require a build system. So depending on a project which is built with Maven/Gradle/Bazel is only possible through dependencies.

"IntelliJ IDEA kotlin project" sounds like you might not even have a build system which pretty much rules out running from command line, even if direct linking was possible. In the next sections I'll assume Gradle, because that's what I'm familiar with, but equivalents could work otherwise in other systems.

Before I go down the rabbit hole, I would like to call [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/), just because you might not need a .kts, a simple `main.kt` with `fun main()` could work as well. And then running with `java -jar` on the resulting app or `gradlew :module:run --args "..."` would just work normally without any special treatment. Oddly enough just today I read [this article](https://dev.to/autonomousapps/tools-of-the-build-trade-the-making-of-a-tiny-kotlin-app-3eba) which describes in detail how to make a small easily-runnable Kotlin app.

One option is that you use `@file:Import`, but I haven't gotten it to work, and it seems [others neither](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/auto-completion-in-kotlin-main-kts-scripts-which-uses-file-import/24595).

`<rabbithole>` So the only workable idea I have for this is that you have your library publish a jar to local repository ([Gradle `mavenLocal()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local)) or import from a local build folder ([flatDir or with `maven { url = file://`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-types)). Note that these are Gradle APIs, which means that Gradle can publish to these in some way.

At this point we have a .jar file of your library in `src/main/kotlin` on the local file system. `.main.kts` files can import JARs from Maven repositories ([example](https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.cinema/blob/af4965c91b892ab4e58c5859e59ecf8e1f1981af/map/map.main.kts#L12-L21)). If you're lucky this built-in `@file:Repository` also supports local `file://` URIs, so it "just works".

Note: location of `.main.kts` files don't matter, only their file name, which makes a huge difference.

The developer experience with this solution would be:

- write code in `src/main/kotlin`
- write unit tests in `src/test/kotlin`
- build
- refresh classpath of `app.main.kts` after build
- code as normal because code completion works (navigation might not)

`</rabbithole>`, notice that the above is pretty much the same as having a `main.kt` file in your app, with the difference that `main.kt` is fully supported and you can do things like pre-compilation, minification, packaging.

---

You can find some `.main.kts` examples here: https://github.com/TWiStErRob/TWiStErRob-env/search?q=filename%3Amain.kts, but they're not using local code, all single-file only with `mavenCentral()` dependencies.

Comment: I see, thanks. I hope IntelliJ makes the scenario create-and-run-a-kotlin-script-that-uses-my-projects-classes-and-functions easier. Kotlin scripting is a nice way to integration test, explore etc.

Comment: BTW, I added an answer describing the workaround that I currently use.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I currently use is to put `.kts` files inside the source root, i.e. somewhere inside `src/main/kotlin` or `src/test/kotlin`.

This works pretty well:

- code completion works
- script can use dependencies
- script can use functions/classes from the project
- running and debugging from inside IntelliJ works

But I get the following warning in IntelliJ:

> This script is not supposed to be inside source root. After Kotlin 1.9
> it will be ignored during the module compilation.

[image]

The 'More info' link is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52735 .